# TeXworks and pvc parameter of latexmk

Tags: texworks, latexmk

When we use TeXworks as editor is there any point in using `-pvc` argument of `latexmk`?

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer here is 'no'. Following [daleif's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/126911), testing using a command-line `latexmk` run

```
latexmk -pvc -pdf -view=none <filename>
```

shows that the TeXworks PDF viewer does not update automatically: you need to force it to reread the PDF file by for example closing the viewer window and reopening.

Setting up `latexmk -pvc` as a typesetting option in TeXworks gives the problem daleif suggested: as the run never stops, TeXworks doesn't try to load the PDF and so you never see anything.

I guess if you do want this workflow, you really need to pick a different editor: at present it's not possible to use the TeXworks editor window 'tied' to a different PDF viewer. (You could just not let TeXworks open its PDF view, but then you've got no SyncTeX between the edit and view windows, which seems a bit of a pain.)

Answer (score 2):

That depends. `latexmk` has both the `-pv` (run previewer after compilation), which TW already does. But `-pvc` is something more. It is continuous preview mode, in which `latexmk` will listen for changes in the source files/included files in your project, including gfx, packages, the class etc. When a change is detected (it looks every few seconds) it will automatically start compiling. Start a previewer and go back to listening afterwards.

This is actually my preferred way of using `LaTeX`, I've reconfigured it slightly such that it does not halt on error and such that it does not spawn/reload a previewer since my Evince is not supported anyway.

I'm not sure if `-pvc` will work with TW, because it might look to see if `latexmk` has terminated and then it will update the previewer. But in `-pvc` `latexmk` never terminates.

Just for the record here is the *don't halt an error* that I have placed in my `.latexmkrc`:

```
$pdflatex = "pdflatex -synctex=1  -halt-on-error %O %S";
```

Comment: I guess therefore 'it depends on your workflow': I tend only to save when I Ctrl-T to typeset, so for me it wouldn't be very helpful :-)

Comment: Not really no. Not that I don't call `latexmk` from my editor either. It have it running in a terminal under my editor.

Comment: OK, makes sense: I did some tests, see my answer.