# Configure latexmk in TeXworks (TeX Live 2013)

Tags: texlive, texworks, latexmk

I am trying to configure latexmk in TeXworks 0.4.5 accompanied by TeX Live 2013.

I followed [the instructions on the TeXworks site](https://code.google.com/p/texworks/wiki/AdvancedTypesettingTools#latexmk), as noted in the picture below:

[image: **TeXworks latexmk configuration]

My code is very simple as follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{report}

\begin{document}
This is my first latex test.
\newpage
how are you.
\newpage
This is a new line.
\newpage
This is another line.
\end{document}
```

But I cannot compile it. The error message is:

```
Latexmk: Stopping because executing following code from command line
    $pdflatex=q/pdflatex -synctex=1 %O %S
gave an error:
    Can't find string terminator "/" anywhere before EOF at (eval 8) line 1.

C:\texlive\2013\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:650: command failed with exit code 2:
perl.exe c:/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/scripts/latexmk/latexmk.pl -e "$pdflatex=q/pdflatex -synctex=1 %O %S" -pdf test.tex
```

I also followed the steps in [configure latexmk in Texworks 0.2.3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18936/configure-latexmk-in-texworks-0-2-3). However it also failed in the end.

After that, I switched to TeXstudio which is configured beforehand:

```
latexmk -pdf -silent -pdflatex="pdflatex -synctex=1 %%O %%S" %
```

Although this works in TeXstudio, it does not compile my code in real-time mode, which behaves as the normal pdfLaTeX command.

1. What reference should I refer to for latexmk?
2. Is latexmk not compatible with TeXworks (TeX Live 2013)?

Comment: In the link you give, there is an additional `/` in one of the lines: `$pdflatex=q/pdflatex $synctexoption %O %S/`. Can you try adding that? (Error seems to be about `/` chars, so looks like a place to start.)

Comment: @JosephWright No error comes out! But it still does not compile as expected. I hope latexmk auto-compiles my tex file while I am editing such as adding a new word. But with the configuration above, I still need to manually compile the code for real effect.

Comment: It sounds like you want latexmk to 'follow' file changes. TeXworks (and indeed most GUIs) aren't well set up for that as it expects the typesetting process to exit before displaying the PDF, which never happens in a 'follow' situation. I think in the past the suggestion to do this has been to use a separate viewer such as Sumatra and have latexmk running from _e.g._ the command line.

Comment: See for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96173/texworks-and-pvc-parameter-of-latexmk and daleif's comment on his own answer

Comment: @JosephWright texworks's feature "typesetting process to exit before displaying the PDF" does not prevent a "follow" situation, I think. TeXworks starts two instances, one for editing, another for preview.

Comment: @JosephWright I read that post. Indeed, from latexmk offical manual, I found that we need to add an extra parameter **-pvc** among other parameters mentioned in my post to latexmk command.

Comment: @Zachary So you were able to solve this? If so, it would be nice if you could write an answer describing the details. (It's perfectly OK, even encouraged, to answer your own question.)